# Как вставить данные из MySql в scrollArea QT

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Подключил базу данных MySQL к окну в QT(думаю что подключил так как ошибки не выдает), а вот как сделать так чтобы в моем списке загружались данные из этой базы данных я не знаю. Подскажите как загружать данные из БД в список(у меня эта штука называется scrollArea) или киньте ссылку на то как это сделать?

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
       db.setHostName("localehost");
       db.setDatabaseName("details");
       db.setUserName("root");
       db.setPassword("root");
       bool ok = db.open();

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton Cancel = QMessageBox::question(this, "Выход", "Выйти?",
                                                               QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    if (Cancel == QMessageBox::Yes){
        QApplication::quit();
    }else{
        qDebug() << "Button 'Yes' was not clicked";
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_scrollArea_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
   //тут должен быть список из БД
}
```

Comment: смотри Qt'шные [sql примеры](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-sql.html). Можешь начать с первого...